# New column in R which is cumulative counting (adding up) unique dates

Tags: r

I have a question regarding creating a new specific variable in a large dataset (36000 rows). I want to create a variable that is cumulative counting the days. So for example:

```
Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
01-01-2018
01-01-2018
02-01-2018
02-01-2018
02-01-2018
02-01-2018
03-01-2018
03-01-2018
```

I want to create the following numeric variable which counts the unique days in order, so:

```
New Variable
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
```

So, the first unique date gets a 1, the second unique date a 2, etc. In total I have more than 36000 observations, where there are 1096 unique dates (three years). So I want a variable that is having a 1 for the first date, a two for the second date, and a 1096 for the last date. However, the dates do not appear equally: one unique date appears maybe 30 times, the other unique date 50 times.

How can I create a variable like this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

- if you are certain that they are ordered correctly, then you can use:

  ```
  cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x$Date) != 0))
  # [1] 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5
  ```
- if you are not certain or just want to guard against it, you can borrow from how `factor`s are stored:

  ```
  # randomize the data for this example
  set.seed(2)
  x <- x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x))),,drop=FALSE]
  x
  #         Date
  # 2 2018-01-01
  # 5 2018-01-02
  # 4 2018-01-02
  # 1 2018-01-01
  # 6 2018-01-02
  # 3 2018-01-02
  # 7 2018-01-03
  # 8 2018-01-03

  # this is the real work, works even if ordered
  x$NewVar <- as.integer(factor(x$Date))
  x
  #         Date NewVar
  # 2 2018-01-01      1
  # 5 2018-01-02      2
  # 4 2018-01-02      2
  # 1 2018-01-01      1
  # 6 2018-01-02      2
  # 3 2018-01-02      2
  # 7 2018-01-03      3
  # 8 2018-01-03      3

  # reorder for presentation here:
  x[order(x$NewVar),]
  #         Date NewVar
  # 2 2018-01-01      1
  # 1 2018-01-01      1
  # 5 2018-01-02      2
  # 4 2018-01-02      2
  # 6 2018-01-02      2
  # 3 2018-01-02      2
  # 7 2018-01-03      3
  # 8 2018-01-03      3
  ```

---

Data:

```
x <- read.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, text="
Date
01-01-2018
01-01-2018
02-01-2018
02-01-2018
02-01-2018
02-01-2018
03-01-2018
03-01-2018")
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Sorry, I noticed I had swapped the `%d` and `%m`, it was clear in your question. No change to the code, now it just looks more correct.